# Why does my program return inf when I try to calculate the Mean Absolute Deviation?

Tags: c++, for-loop

When I call the getDeviation function all it returns is 'inf' and I am not sure why. And I think the problem is in the for-loop in the getDeviation function, but I am not sure whats wrong with it. I am also a beginner to c++ so i'm sorry if there is a lot of stuff I screwed up on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double getAverage(int amount, int numbers[])
{
    // Declare the variables
    double total = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    //Find each number in the array then add it to the total
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        total += numbers[i];
    }
    //Divide the total by the amount to get the average
    avg = total / amount;
    cout << "The Average is: " << avg << "\n";
    //Return back to the functions original state
    return 0;
}

double getDeviation(int amount, int numbers[], double avg)
{
    //Declare the variables and arrays
    int absoluteNums[1000] = {};
    double tempNum = 0;
    double absoNum = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double deviation = 0;

    //Search for each number, subtract the mean, make it an absolute value, then store it in another array
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        tempNum += numbers[i];
        absoNum = abs(tempNum);
        numbers[i] = absoNum;
        numbers[i] -= avg;
        total += numbers[i];
    }

    //Divide the total by the average to get the deviation
    if (avg == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        deviation = total / avg;
        cout << "The Mean Absolute Deviation is: " << deviation << "\n";
    }
    //Return back to the functions original state
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Declare the variables and arrays
    int varNum = 1;
    int totVar = 0;
    int userNums[1000] = {};
    double avg;
    //Ask user for how many variables they want then record it
    cout << "How many variables would you like to have? (Max 999) ";
    cin >> totVar;
    //Check if totVar is to big
    if (totVar >= 1000) {
        cout << "To big. Nice try though!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
    for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i) {
        cout << "Please input variable " << varNum << ": ";
        cin >> userNums[i];
        varNum++;
    }
    //Make the avg value the average of the numbers using the getAverage function
    avg = getAverage(totVar, userNums);
    //Call the average function
    getAverage(totVar, userNums);
    //Call the deviation function
    getDeviation(totVar, userNums, avg);
    //Return back to the functions original state
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in the debugger and watching the values?

Comment: Yes for over an hour I think. I'm kind of new to this language.

Comment: `total` variable is not initialized. So this code `total += numbers[i];` invokes an undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you find the point where it computes infinity? I expect that 1/0 would compute inf.

Comment: Still doesn't work after I initialized it.

Comment: Set breakpoint at this line `deviation = total / avg;` see `total` and `avg` values. If `avg` is 0, then you first have to create protection from the zero division, secondly - search for error in your `getAverage` function.

Comment: Does that have something to do with the loop? If it does please do iterate.

Comment: Hint: Look what getAverage() returns.

Comment: Why does `getAverage()` always return 0, and the caller ignores that value, calls it again, and ignores that result?

Comment: I set an if statement to protect it from dividing by zero, but now it doesn't output anything. I edit what I wrote into the question above, but does it have something to do with making it an absolute value?

Comment: Ahhhhh. I see know, it works when you return the deviation instead of 0. Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**

`total` is used before initialized in `getDeviation()`.

You should **always** initialize variable before using them.

```
double absoNum = 0;
double total = 0;
double deviation = 0;
```

**2.**

`getAverage()` returns 0 at the last line. It should return `avg`.

**3.**

`getDeviation()` returns 0 at the last line. It should return `deviation`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. :D